# Gah, these number sequences are just too boring!

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, sequence

*Gah, these number sequences are just too boring! You just plug them in and then you're done!*

There is a function $f : \mathcal{S} \to \mathbb{Z}$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is a finite subset of the positive integers that are $10 \pmod{16}$. It is known that $$f(59188506) = 127, ~f(101156906) = 108, ~f(51786282)=112, ~f(72562458)=97.$$

In addition, for many of the elements in $\mathcal{S}$, the value of $f$ is either zero or one.

What is $f$?

Comment: Truly, a very nice "number sequence puzzle"!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$f(n)$ is the function which

> takes the hexadecimal representation of $n$, reverses it, and if the result is a valid A-number for an OEIS entry, returns the first member of the corresponding sequence.

Specifically,

> $59188506_{10} = 387251A_{16}$, and [A152783](https://oeis.org/A152783) begins $\boxed{127}, 607, 4423, \dots$
>  $101156906_{10} = 607882A_{16}$, and [A288706](https://oeis.org/A288706) begins $\boxed{108}, 614, 3840, \dots$
>  $51786282_{10} = 316322A_{16}$, and [A223613](https://oeis.org/A223613) begins $\boxed{112}, 6592, 124672, \dots$
>  $72562458_{10} = 453371A_{16}$, and [A173354](https://oeis.org/A173354) begins $\boxed{97}, 37840, 199652, \dots$

Comment: That's it, great job!